# Not Getting the object in template Django

Tags: python, ajax, json, django

I am getting the error that json not serializable.

views.py

```
def get_post(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method=="GET":
            craves = CraveData.objects.filter(person=request.user)
            print craves
            response = json.dumps({"craves":craves})
            return HttpResponse(response,mimetype="application/json")
```

crave.html

```
function next(){
                    alert("you in")
                $.ajax({
                                url: "/crave/get_post/",
                                type: "GET",
                                data: "",
                                success: function(response){
                                    alert('success');
                                    alert(response.craves)
                                    //$('.ajaxProgress').html(response.HTML_USER);
                                    $('.ajaxProgress').html(response.craves);                                   
                                },
                                error:function(){
                                    alert('some error');
                                }
                }); 
            }
```

I am getting `TypeError: [<CraveData: Gaurav>, <CraveData: Rahul>] is not JSON serializable`

but when i tried to get

```
craves = len(CraveData.objects.filter(person=request.user))
```

I am getting the value. Please help me out to get objects in templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a proper [serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/):

```
from django.core import serializers

def get_post(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method=="GET":
            craves = CraveData.objects.filter(person=request.user)
            response = serializers.serialize('json', craves)
            return HttpResponse(response, mimetype="application/json")
```

Comment: Hay getting  [{"pk":1,"model":"crave.cravedata","fields":{"date":"2014-04-28T13:36:07.038Z","person":1,"post":"Gaurav"}},{"pk":2,"model":"crave.cravedata","fields":{"date":"2014-04-28T13:46:33.552Z","person":1,"post":"Rahul"}}] all this data. But i want only post to display. I used var p = JSON.stringify(response);